# Unable to retrive text from server to edittext

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

i have to retrieve text from the server and display it in Edit Text. 
here is my code. i am putting this code in the onCreate method.

```
    EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_usr_nam);
    EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
    EditText ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
    String UserName=ed.getText().toString();
    String Name=ed1.getText().toString();
    String Email=ed2.getText().toString();
    String Age=ed3.getText().toString();
    try{
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://abcd");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", UserName));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form", "register"));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", Name));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", Age));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
    String responseText= inputStreamTOString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    System.out.println("errrrooooorrrrrrr"+responseText);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseText);
    json.getString("response");


    ed.setText(json.getString(UserName));
    ed1.setText(json.getString(Name));
    ed2.setText(json.getString(Email));
    ed3.setText(json.getString(Age));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("exvcx", "error getting data" +e.toString());
    }
```

please tell me where i am wrong . thanks

Comment: what problem you have when running this code?

Comment: `exvcx(861): error getting dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: add full json data which you are getting from Server

Comment: if you provide json then we will help you more.

Comment: `A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

select *,u.name fname,c.name cityname, s.name statename from users u left outer join cities c on u.city_id=c.id left outer join states s on s.id=c.state_id left outer join interests i on i.id=u.interest_ids where u.id=



Line Number: 108
`

Comment: this is the error when i enter my url in browser.

Comment: Search "errrrooooorrrrrrr" line in logcat you will get json from logcat also

Comment: It's a very very bad design when you make network calls in your onCreate() method, it must be done in a separate thread.

Comment: 07-06 12:44:46.250: INFO/System.out(861): errrrooooorrrrrrr<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Database Error</title><style type="text/css">::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }body {    background-color: #fff;    margin: 40px;    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;    color: #4F5155;}a {    color: #003399;    background-color: transparent;    font-weight: normal;}h1 {    color: #444;    background-color: transparent;

Comment: font-size: 19px;    font-weight: normal;    margin: 0 0 14px 0;    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;}code {    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;    font-size: 12px;    background-color: #f9f9f9;    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;    color: #002166;    display: block;    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;}#container {    margin: 10px;    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;}p {    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;}</style></head><body>    <div id="container">    <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>        <p>Error Number: 1064</p>

Comment: @Egor +1. In 4.x all the network requests must be done in a non ui thread. If not, then the request is not done and always throws an Exception. Take it under consideration

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nothing wrong on your code.

**My advice**: Make sure you check that your php file at your server is working.

You said you got these errors if you go access directly by browser:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 select *,u.name
>   fname,c.name cityname, s.name statename from users u left outer join
>   cities c on u.city_id=c.id left outer join states s on s.id=c.state_id
>   left outer join interests i on i.id=u.interest_ids where u.id= Line
>   Number: 108

Looks like your database query seems wrong.

What should you do? Fix the query. Then test and debug by sending a dummy parameters to your php and get it working.

Then you can continue on your android programming :)